# Monitor Change in MySQL DataBase

Tags: php, android

So , i have a MySQL DataBase , from my Html/Php Page , i can Access it and read somes Values and show it in the web Page ,

my Problem :

On the other side , an Android App will also Modify the DataBase , and somes Values , so i have to click on Refresh Button from the Web Browser where the Data are Shown ,

Is there any way to constantly Monitor the DataBase for any Changes on a special Row for example , then Update it on the Html Page , i tried this Code with no Luck :

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $One=$_SESSION['One']; 
 $Two=$_SESSION['Two'];  
 $Three=$_SESSION['Three']; 
 $Four=$_SESSION['Four']; 
 $tbl_name =$_SESSION['Five']; 
 // Connect to server and select databse.
 mysql_connect("$One", "$Two", "$Three")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$Four")or die("cannot select DB");
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT message FROM $tbl_name WHERE pass='".$_SESSION['pass']."'");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){

 }
while(true!=false)
 echo $row['message'];
 ?>
 <head>
 <html>
 <body>


<title>Title</title>
<div><h2><?php echo 'I found something in the session: ' .$_SESSION['text']?></h2>   </div>
 </br>
 </br>


 </body>
 </html>
 </head>
```

Comment: are you sure, you have to use database ? from my point of view, it looks like a chat application where socket would be a more suitable choice, or make use of ajax since its a website in middle.. also its considered a bad thing to store information for database connection in sessions. `mysql_*` functions are not recommended, try PDO, and i believe there is a better way to use that `while` loop.

Comment: this is to Communicate from the Web Browser To the Android Device , the Mechanism i choosen , is to put 'SomeMessage' in the row 'Message' in the DataBase from an Html Button , then the Android Application will keep checking the DataBase for any Change in this Table/Row , and will Answer in the Row 'response' , this is my Problem , the row 'response' must be shown with 'echo' Function or Anything ...

Comment: and Yes , i need DB to store Others Informations ...

Comment: I Noticed whatever i try to do for an infinite loop will result to an Error 'No Data Received from the WebSite' ...